Problem with least squares rational approximation to `asin(x)+ sqrt(1-x^2)` in [3,1] form
I'm trying to generate a decent [3,1] rational least squares polynomial approximation to asin(x)+sqrt(1-x^2) on [0,1] and failing dismally :(
The problem is that it has a pole for this particular combination and also a handful of others (approx. 1%) of those I tested rational approximations to this function go completely haywire. This is the first step in a Remez equal ripple code.
I have ported the original Julia code which works in arbitrary precision (so numerical instability can be ruled out) to C and get about the same results as the Julia code for modest N,D. I still find debugging easier in C/C++. The algebra all looks fine to me and it works in ~99% of cases for N, D <= 20. It uses a trick described here asin when fast sqrt available. This is of interest again because hardware sqrt is now so fast.
Unfortunately the equation is rather fickle and rational Remez solutions to it are a bit thin on the ground. When the original author tried it he listed all the solutions that were soluble in Maple/Mathematica with digits = 30 for N, D <= 20 at the end. My improvements have got past some of the obstacles. I expect Maple & Mathematica have also improved in the meantime.
The remaining failing cases in the full Julia implementation are (my C code can duplicate them up to N+D ~9):



D
Fails
Failing N values




0
0



1
1
3


2
1
6


3
1
9


4
3
4   12  14


5
3
1   7   17


6
2
10  20


7
2
1   13


8
3
8   16  18


9
2
5   11


10
2
2   14


11
1
17


12
4
2   6   12  20


13
2
9   15


14
1
18


15
2
3   7


16
2
10  16


17
4
3   7   13  19


18
0



19
2
11  17


20
4
4   8   14  20



Total failures  42/400

There is a sort of pattern visible in the failures. Notably that the first failures occur in pairs at N, D=5N and D=5N+2 [1,5][1,7], [2,10][2,12], [3,15][3,17] and the other heuristic is that failing ones tend to be at an offset at N+1, D+3 or N+1, D+5 from a previous failing one at N,D. I have no idea why this is.
My concrete question is can someone else please try and construct a rational polynomial [3,1] that will fit this function and does not have a pole in the denominator or if that isn't possible (and I begin to think that it might not be suggestions on how else to tame asin(x)as x->1). I'm using x_n = sin(pi*n/N)^2 Chebyshev  for the x coordinates which places more emphasis on fitting the ends of the range (equal spaced is worse). I'm wondering about increasing the density of points sampled at larger x values. Increasing the weights there didn't help.
These are the (truncated coefficients for the various polynomials along the slice N+D = 4 to which [3,1] belongs.



N
D
a0
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
chisq
min
max




4
0
0.9995526
1.0122944
-0.56767465
0.28349546
-0.1558162
1
3.603E-06
-0.0004863
0.001055


3
1
1.0003446
-0.138900694
-1.51998173
0.463582739
1
-1.1239944
0.00026536
-0.0119395
0.0069909


2
2
0.9999087
0.845226481
-0.950516017
1
-0.1583922
-0.2722624
1.2614E-06
-0.00036045
0.00051565


1
3
0.9997
2.270119177
1
1.248325161
-0.536562537
0.368
1.6649E-05
-0.000982
0.0014115


0
4
1.0014
1
-0.959053269
1.152066248
-0.849712791
0.29415
6.8462E-06
-0.00051585
0.0014


3
1
1.000688
0.08167677
-1.276224508
0.356408177
1
-0.8965724
1.11E-05
-0.0007097
0.0008207



These are the respective error graphs on the same scale for each of the approximations above (the adjusted [3,1] isn't shown but just looks like a W). A correct solution with 6 extrema should look like W\ or /W ie HLHLHL or the opposite. Note the pole going off to infinity on the red [3,1] curve at x = 0.8897.



AOBE I would probably use [2,2] or [3,2] as the best trade off on simplicity vs accuracy. But [3,1] would be very handy if it exists.
I have omitted the customary MRE for the moment since it isn't really minimal. I hope to get it down to under 400 lines without removing any of the crucial explanatory comments. It is a one to one code match for the ARM Remez Julia as far as is possible which makes the C rather ugly (I'm not especially proud of it but it does work and gets the same answers as Julia in the range N+D< 9. Obviously numerical stability is an issue with only double precision and the matrix solver from Julia is crude but it works well enough for [3,1] not to be a problem.
I have tried weighting the fit and various analytic transformations to move excess coefficient value from the denominator into the numerator and obtained a sort of solution at the bottom of the table but which doesn't oscillate enough to be acceptable input for Remez. Remez also tends to restore the pole and/or create new ones (but that is another story).
My goal is to have N+D+2 extrema in the rational least squares approximation including the two end points. An interesting curiosity is that [0,4] actually has N+D+3 extrema due to serendipity. The other low order ones giving problems with poles are [1,5], [1,7], [4,4] and [6,1]. I have focused on [3,1] specifically because I had hoped that analytic methods for cubic equations might allow me to find a well behaved solution - if one exists. That approach got me past the previous gotcha which triggered on a quadratic form [0,2] and I had hoped that was the last bug in this section.
If an ideal equal ripple solution to target f(x) with error e and 6 extrema does exist we have a couple of hard algebraic constraints that can be used to decrease the search space or to sanity check putative answers. Based on the values taken at the ends of the range x = 0 and x=1.
 r(x) = (a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3)/(1-gx)

 f(0) - r(0) = e = 1 - a    IOW a = 1 - e
 f(1) - r(0) = -e = pi/2 - (a+b+c+d)/(1-g)
 IOW
 a+b+c+d = (pi/2+e)(1-g)
 so d = (pi/2+e)(1-g)-1+e+b+c
 And also to avoid having a pole in the range 0 - 1
 g < 1 

I'm now looking at tricks from solving the cubic and knowing that a final solution with the right number of extrema in the target range 0-1 must have a derivative with a numerator with all real roots in the same range. This approach is proving tough. I suspect possibly because no such solution exists (brute force on the four remaining free parameters hasn't found one yet either). I can take a guess at a value for e ~ 0.0014 and then try all legal combos of b,c,d,g but it still isn't yeilding...

"[C]an someone else please try and construct a rational polynomial [3,1] that will fit this function and does not have a pole in the denominator[?]" sounds like a math problem, not a programming problem. Have you considered whether it might be more suitable for Mathematics SE?

I did consider it but I know several people with rational optimisation codes frequent SO and may be able to shed some light on why this particular and fairly innocent looking function is such a PITA to approximate (but only for a handful of awkward cases). I can't tell at the moment if it is a programming problem or a maths problem. I'm more inclined to blame the code. But I've run out of ideas.

The question is interesting, and very thorough, but "People who can answer may see it here" is not a criterion for whether it is on-topic for SO.  "Please construct a polynomial for me" is not on topic, nor is "why does this function have the properties it does?".  Perhaps there's a way to refocus it on a programming problem scoped narrowly enough for SO, but it's not immediately evident to me what that way would be.

@JohnBollinger some aspects of this question are math, yet this still has various coding issues.

@MartinBrown "I'm more inclined to blame the code." --> Posting that code would help.

I have exhausted all the tricks I know to get a solution and presented the simplest example of a problem case [3,1] where my code fails together with the classical least squares solution obtained (with a pole in it) and the best lsq fit that I have been able to construct by other means. This problem with rational approximations and poles is well known and the usual advice is to choose another nearby pair of [N,D] and pray. But for very specific reasons I really want to find a better one for [3,1].

@chux It feels a bit long to be an MRE though ~400 lines (and not a lot of scope for shortening it whilst retaining enough functionality to demo the problem).

@MartinBrown, It’s pretty tough to get 10^-6 accuracy with a [3,1] polynomial because it just doesn’t have enough flexibility with only 5 coefficients. That's not saying it can't be done through piecewise approximation combining different techniques. The accuracy you require can likely be achieved fairly easily with Chebyshev approximation, although it's not clear if that's an option for you.

@Martin Brown Re taming in other ways. Here is an approach for arccos(x) due to R. Harley that you may want to try to adapt for arcsin(x). Let t := |x|, t in [0,1], and u := 1-t, u in [0,1]. We observe arccos(t) ≈/2·√u. Let s := √(2·u), then arccos(x) ≈ sgn(x) · fma (P(u) · u, s, s), where P(u) is an approximation to arccos(t) / s - 1, which is well behaved (almost linear) on [0,1]. For numerical reasons the approximation is unlikely to achieve full accuracy across the entire input domain, but it should be fine when tight ulp error bounds are not required.

@njuffa thanks for that novelty! I hadn't seen it before. I'll have to see if it will work in may application (I suspect not but it is still worth a try).

@Martin Brown I see I made a small mistake in my previous comment, please read " ... where P(u) · u is an approximation to arccos(t) / s - 1 ..." How fast is the square root in your case? I am currently exploring Borchardt's algorithm with convergence acceleration for computing the arctangent, motivated by this question. This is presumably also applicable to other inverse trig functions.

@njuffa in the right circumstance sqrt on my i5-12600 seems to be as fast as or perhaps sometimes faster than divide. I don't know how they manage to do that! Thanks for the pointer to the other question tan & arctan are also on my hit list. I'm particularly interested in high accuracy low order polynomial approximations on limited ranges. I'm also becoming interested in magic combinations of instructions which happen to run much faster than you might reasonably expect. Problem with that is that every time I try to  make an MRE the effect vanishes :(

@Martin Brown High-radix SRT or iterative methods at the core of division and square root basically have the same complexity for either operation, but square root has only one argument and no overflow/underflow cases. If square root is in fact faster than division, that would likely only be by one cycle, though. Example: On a recent ARM64 microarchitecture (Neoverse 2) double-precision division is 7-15 cycles and square root is 7-16 cycles (latency), but for single precision it is 7-10 cycles for division and 7-9 cycles for square root.

@MartinBrown Any issues remaining?

@Chux Thanks. I hadn't noticed your modified answer until just now. The problem can best be described as fickle. I'm not concerned that the solution is a bit useless - the whole purpose was to have a very hard test case to break (and validate) the main code. Based on this hard won test solution I was able to make the main program able to handle N,1 and 1,D (mostly). You are right that ULP would be better but I simplified it to absolute error to shorten the MRE. I'd still love to have an explanation of the pattern of failing N,D pairs but the maths forum remains quiet. Busy on other work now.

[2024 Oct 23]
Prior optimization based on using an incorrect formula (not shown here).
Fixed.

I used the following (which is close to OP's answer.):
op(x) = asin(x) + sqrt(1 - x*x)
poly(x) = (((c3*x + c2)*x + c1)*x + c1)/(d1*x + 1)
c0   1.00058937815264
c1   0.0111306086313463
c2  -1.35415225023654
c3   0.390636229113996
d1  -0.969300884013643

It had a maximum absolute error of 0.00059.


I'm now looking at tricks ...

Found via office libre(or maybe excel) solver optimizing over about 100 data points.

[4,0]
Perhaps  poly(x) = (((c4*x + c3)*x + c2)*x + c1)*x + c0) would have been better, even though OP asked for a decent [3,1]?
Constraining f(0) == 1.0 and f(1) to about pi/2 to fit nicely at the end points, I came up with:
c0   1
c1   1.00338973779371
c2  -0.483991222682364
c3   0.219301937693067
c4  -0.167904125088803

... with a max error of 0.00048.


Yet IMHO, these are weak solutions.
Rather than try to minimize the max absolute error, the ULP error should be minimized and the end points should be very precise.
Yet since f(x), is in the x = [0.0 ... 1.0] domain only has an output in the f(x) = [1.0 ... 1.571) range, (the same power-of-2), optimizing to minimal absolute error is like minimizing the ULP error.

thanks for your answer. My brute force attack has yielded a promising answer with about half the ripple error (it has been very hard won). The difference in the parameter values demonstrates how fickle this problem is and how easily conventional optimisers get stuck on refining some local optimum. They are  c0 = 1.0006788  c1 = 0.0822 c2 =  -1.277439  c3 =   0.3571357465 d1 =   -0.89654635  max err   6.78881379e-04. Not been able to improve on it for a while now. There is a line of possible solutions from yours to mine with radically different c2, d1 values (and c2,c3 tweaked to match).

Brute force eventually won out and the true solution was surprisingly close to where my optimiser found itself stuck. The solution isn't quite equal ripple yet due to the limitations of working in double precision but it does have the right number of extrema (something I had virtually given up on) and it is slightly better (10%) than the interim solution that I added in a comment to @chux. I'm not sure the improvement is worth the all effort lavished on it but if it can be automated in the approximation code then it will have been worthwhile.
The final solution is:
f = (1.000575914 + x*(0.010718119 + x*(-1.354982413+x*0.391028257)))/(1 - x*0.969851881)

The peak residuals are:
-0.000575914, 0.000587064, -0.00059901, 0.000593465, -0.000547132, 0.00055321
Max ripple error just under 6e-4 might even be under 5.9e-4.

About 10% tighter bounds than the inferior solution found comparatively easily.

Yes. Its a copy and paste mistake. I'll fix it in the answer.
